# Strings in C Programming Language

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str3[6] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
    char str4[ ] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'}; 
    printf("%s, %s", str3, str4);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output for this is :
hello, hellohello

Why two times hello ????

Comment: `str4` is just an array of characters, not a string.

Comment: As an experiment, try defining `str4` before `str3`. You will probably get the output `hello, hello<some gibberish here>` or a segmentation violation.

Comment: @IanAbbott I tried ```str4``` before ```str3``` but it just gives the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str4` has no 0-terminator, so `printf` keeps reading out of bounds of the array and by luck (or not) there seems to be `str3` directly behind `str4`, so it reads till the 0-terminator of `str3`.

In the end ==> undefined behavior, don't rely on that.

Comment: ooh, i see, but even when i change the order of their output i.e. ```str4``` before ```str3``` the same output is being displayed.

Comment: Yes, there is no guarantee for the order of the variables in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

`str4` does not contain a null terminator. Since `str4` and `str3` are sequentially allocated on the stack by the compiler, the second `%s` in the `printf` will start printing `str4` and due to the lack of a null terminator continue with printing `str3`.